# How to make a List of Async Tasks add elements to an Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, observablecollection

I am trying to convert the following method to run in parallel:

```
List<(DateTime start, DateTime end)> dates = CreateDateListTuple();

foreach ((DateTime start, DateTime end) date in dates)
        {
            dBInfos.Add(await GetDBInfo(date.start, date.end));
        }
```

What I tried to attempt, is first creating a list of tasks:

```
List<Task<DBInfo>> parallelTasks = new List<Task<>>;

foreach((DateTime start,DateTime end) date in dates)
        {
            parallelTasks.Add(GetDBInfo(date.start, date.end));
        }
```

Then running these tasks in parallel:

```
var continuation = await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks.ToArray());
continuation.Wait();
```

Then adding the results to the collection:

```
foreach (var result in continuation.Result)
        {
            dBInfos.Add(result);
        }
```

What happens, is that the program freezes on the

> continuation.Wait();

command, without throwing any exceptions. What could be wrong with the implementation?

Comment: The `Task.WhenAll` is able to return `Task<TResult[]>` when calling `Task.WhenAll<Result>(...)`   [Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___)   (dotnet 5)

Comment: I have updated the question based on this information, thank you!

Comment: What is the type of the `continuation` variable? And why `.Wait()`? Why `.Result`? [Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by rewriting the end of the code to:

```
        DBInfo[] continuation = await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks.ToArray());

        foreach (DBInfo result in continuation)
        {
            dBInfos.Add(result);
        }
```